# flyway Default placeholders in POM.XML

Tags: spring-boot, maven, flyway

Can I use a flyway "Default placeholder" in POM.XML ?  for example ${flyway.url}, ${flyway.user}  and ${flyway.password} ?  Will Flyway replace these placeholders with the values defined in application.properties or application.yaml files at runtime before maven executes the pom ?

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <url>${flyway.url}</url>
                <user>${flyway.user}</user>
                <password>${flyway.password}</password>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>${oracle.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to share the config between Maven and Spring would probably be the following:

**src/main/resources/application.properties**

```
spring.flyway.username=${flyway.username}
spring.flyway.password=${flyway.password}
...

flyway.username=user
flyway.password=SecretPa$$word
```

**pom.xml**

```
<properties>
    <flyway.configFiles>${project.baseDir}/src/main/resources/application.properties</flyway.configFiles>
</properties>
```

Alternatively, you can use the Properties Maven Plugin:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <files>
                <file>${project.baseDir}/src/main/resources/application.properties</file>
              </files>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

If you want to have Flyway properties in a separate `.properties` file, you can also use Maven resource filtering on the `application.properties/application.yaml` files.

Comment: What is the purpose of  spring.flyway.username=${flyway.username}  and   spring.flyway.password=${flyway.password}  in   application.properties ?

Comment: Spring Boot uses `spring.flyway.*` properties, while the Maven plugin expects just `flyway.*`. This setup satisfies both